# Issue in Creating JSON output with key:value as tag names using struct

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I would want to create an output JSON as shown below,

```
{
   "Name": "John Smith",
   "City": "London",
   "Contact": [
     { "key": "StreetName", "value": "SomeName" },
     { "key": "PostalCode", "value": "SomeValue" }
   ],
}
```

I'm trying to achieve this using the code below,

```
package main

import (
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
        "log"
)

type Person struct {
   Name, City string
   Contact ContactStruct   
}

type ContactStruct struct {
   Street, PostalCode map[string]string
}

func main() {
  StreetData := make(map[string]string)
  StreetData["key"] = "StreetName"
  StreetData["value"] = "ABC Street"

  PostalCodeData := make(map[string]string)
  PostalCodeData["key"] = "PostalCode"
  PostalCodeData["value"] = "12345"

  jsonData := Person{
    Name: "John Smith",
    City: "London",
    Contact: ContactStruct{
       StreetData,
       PostalCodeData,
    },
  }

  finalJsonData, err := json.MarshalIndent(jsonData, " ", "   ")
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  fmt.Println(string(finalJsonData))
}
```

Below is the output generated using the above code,

```
 {
    "Name": "John Smith",
    "City": "London",
    "Contact": {
       "Street": {
          "key": "StreetName",
          "value": "ABC Street"
       },
       "PostalCode": {
          "key": "PostalCode",
          "value": "12345"
       }
    }
 }
```

Problem: As we can see, output is getting created with the tag names **"Street"** and **PostalCode**, because we are creating the JSON using struct value.

I've tried explore various options of using `map[string]string` and `map[string]interface{}` inside the `Person struct`. But it is not working.

Is there any better implementation available to get the JSON output, according to my requirement showed at the beginning of the question.

Thanks in advance for the help. I've started developing in golang recently.

Running Source is available here: https://play.golang.org/p/eIxDyWXfZ1C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you want it this way

```
type Person struct {
    Name, City string
    Contact    []ContactStruct
}

type ContactStruct struct {
    Key   string
    Value string
}

func main() {

    StreetData := ContactStruct{Key: "StreetName", Value: "ABC Street"}
    PostalCodeData := ContactStruct{Key: "PostalCode", Value: "12345"}
    jsonData := Person{
        Name:    "John Smith",
        City:    "London",
        Contact: []ContactStruct{StreetData, PostalCodeData},
    }
    finalJsonData, err := json.MarshalIndent(jsonData, " ", "   ")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(finalJsonData))
}
```

Comment: User mindaugas already provided similar solution before. Hence accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is kind of weird, but this is the solution:
https://play.golang.org/p/CCVuiGd5phq

Quick tip: https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ use this page when you need a struct for your json.

Comment: Thanks @mindaugas. This works and creating JSON as expected.

Comment: @SaravananG you want slice of  `ContactStruct ` right ? This solution is different

Comment: Thanks for sharing the json to go url.

Comment: @mindaugas It is not a good approach change the solution in link after posting
I saw your solution earliar its different.

Comment: The solution as currently proposed is fine (probably edited since comments above).

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use a custom JSON marshaler for `ContactStruct`. This allows to keep using a clean Go data type but still implement the specific serialization expected to communicate with the outside world.

View and run on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/eWR34PvXzGj):

```golang
package main

import (
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
        "log"
)

type Person struct {
   Name, City string
   Contact ContactStruct   
}

type ContactStruct struct {
   Street, PostalCode string
}

func appendKV(buf []byte, key string, value string) ([]byte) {
    buf = append(buf, []byte(`{"key":`)...)
    b, _ := json.Marshal(key)
    buf = append(buf, b...)
    buf = append(buf, []byte(`,"value":`)...)
    b, _ = json.Marshal(value)
    buf = append(buf, b...)
    buf = append(buf, '}')
    return buf
}

func (cs ContactStruct) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    buf := []byte{'['}
    buf = appendKV(buf, "StreetName", cs.Street)
    buf = append(buf, ',')
    buf = appendKV(buf, "PostalCode", cs.PostalCode)
    buf = append(buf, ']')
    return buf, nil
}


func main() {
  jsonData := Person{
    Name: "John Smith",
    City: "London",
    Contact: ContactStruct{
       Street: "ABC Street",
       PostalCode: "12345",
    },
  }

  finalJsonData, err := json.MarshalIndent(jsonData, " ", "   ")
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  fmt.Println(string(finalJsonData))
}
```